# Не удаётся обновить Xcode с терминала с помощью mas (Error: No downloads began)

Tags: xcode, консоль, homebrew

Я хотел обновить Xcode(с версии 12.1 к версии 12.4) с помощью терминала с помочью mas но почему то не получается. После того как я ввожу в терминал `mas upgrade <номер Xcode>`то я получаю ошибку `Error: No downloads began`. Почему так?

Comment: как вариант можно использовать app store для обновления данного по

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть несколько вариантов обновления XCODE. Первый через App Store - через яблоко в верхнем левом углу открывайте App Store и там будет список доступных для обновления программ.

[Второй вариант](https://learnappmaking.com/how-to-download-install-update-xcode/) - через HomeBrew. Получаете список программ которые у вас установлены через App Store:

```
mas list
```

находите Xcode:

```
mas search Xcode
```

вам выведет большой список того что есть вместе с Xcode:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вам нужно найти в этом списке только Xcode и рядом с ним будет номер стоять. Вы копируете номер в данную команду:

```
mas upgrade 123456789
```

[Еще один вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617452/how-to-update-xcode-from-command-line) обновления  - через командную строку. Удаляем старые тулы:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Устанавливаем Xcode:

```
xcode-select --install
```